# cannot read SQLite file in mac qt

Tags: macos, sqlite, qt

Database settings:

In. h file.
QSqlDatabase db;

In the CPP file.

```
db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("./realtest.db");
```

Under win, debug,release, it's works well.

However, after migrating to Mac, it was works well at debug. However, after being published as app, the data could not be read.If absolute paths are adopted, such as:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(ReadingSqlConst::SQLITE);   db.setDatabaseName(QString("/Users/apple/Desktop/newztdb/Resources/realtest.db");
```

It's works, but it's  does not works if you take the following path

Method 1:

```
db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase (ReadingSqlConst::SQLITE);
db.setDatabaseName(QString(QApplication::ApplicationDirPath()+"/Resources/realtest.db");
```

Method 2:

```
QDir tempDir;
QString currentDir=tempDir.currentPath();
db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(ReadingSqlConst::SQLITE);
db.setDatabaseName(currentDir+"/Resources/realtest.db");
```

Mode 1 and mode 2 are also abnormal.
I just want to put sqlite's DB file in app. How can I solve it?

Comment: Why do you have spaces in the last 2 paths? Are they present in the directory and file names on disk? Do those bits of code compile?

Comment: Sorry. There are no two spaces in the middle. They have been modified. These codes have been compiled and passed.